# How to Export Jenkins Results to HP ALM QC

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, hp-alm

I am using Jenkins plugin "HP Application Automation Tools" to export job results (JUnit) to HP Quality Center (11.52.xx). Apparently this works fine and it creates the folder where its specified in **Test Folder** and **Test set Folder** fields.

The problem is that it always give me the same error:

```
INFO: 'Upload test result to ALM' Post Build Step is being invoked.
INFO: 1 test result file found.
INFO: Start to upload /jenkinsm/data/jobs/JenkinsTest/builds/22/htmlreports/HTML_Report/TEST-features-JenkinsTest.xml
INFO: Start to parse file: /jenkinsm/data/jobs/JenkinsTest/builds/22/htmlreports/HTML_Report/TEST-features-JenkinsTest.xml
INFO: parse resut file succeed.
INFO: Start to login to ALM Server.
Logged in successfully to ALM Server http://XXXXX/qcbin/ using YYYY
INFO: Checking test folder...
INFO: Checking testset folder...
INFO: Uploading ALM Entities...
```

> **Failed** to create Entity:test-sets:parent-id=105name=JenkinsTest
>   Testsubtype-id=hp.qc.test-set.external

```
INFO: Uploaded /jenkinsm/data/jobs/JenkinsTest/builds/22/htmlreports/HTML_Report/TEST-features-JenkinsTest.xml.
INFO: 'Upload test result to ALM' Completed.
```

I appreciate some suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: I'm getting the same error and looks like someone has an issue open for the same - https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-32004 , and it suggests that the error is due to missing Testsubtype-id in ALM

Answer (score 1):

It can be caused by many reasons, what comes to my mind right now.

Do you customized your project? Maybe you marked some fields for TestSet as required? If you do, automation tool sends just values from default ALM project settings and ALM doesn't allow to create the TestSet because some required field is missing.

Answer (score 1):

According to the HP knowledge base, the integration of Jenkins in HP ALM is only available from Quality Center 12.21, the version you are using does not support the integration:
http://h20230.www2.hp.com/selfsolve/document/KM01698877

Comment: This url appears to require a signin.